# How can I find points at an equal distance between 2 objects?

Tags: math, vector, maya, pymel

I'm trying to find points at an equal distance between 2 other points in 3D space. For example, I have 2 cubes in my scene. I want to add 5 (or 3, or 80...) locators at an equal distance between these two spheres with Pymel.

I can easily find the midway point between the spheres like this:

```
import pymel.core as pm
import pymel.core.datatypes as dt

pos_1, pos_2 = pm.selected()

point_1 = dt.Vector(pos_1.getTranslation())
point_2 = dt.Vector(pos_2.getTranslation())

midway_point = (point_1 + point_2) / 2
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get multiple points on the line between the two spheres.

I tried something like this:

```
import pymel.core as pm
import pymel.core.datatypes as dt

pos_1, pos_2 = pm.selected()

point_1 = dt.Vector(pos_1.getTranslation())
point_2 = dt.Vector(pos_2.getTranslation())

distance = point_1.distanceTo(point_2)
divided_distance = distance / 5

for i in range (1, 5):
    position = point_1 + (divided_distance * i)
    pm.spaceLocator(position = position, absolute = True)
```

Which does add 5 locators between the two spheres, but they're not on the line connecting the two points in 3D space.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you calculate the distance between the two points, you're getting a *scalar*, essentially a single number that is the number of units the points are away from each other. But what you're not getting is the *direction* from one to the other. That would be a *vector*. To get the vector, change this line:

```
distance = point_1.distanceTo(point_2)
```

to this:

```
difference = point_2 - point_1
```

Now instead of getting the single unit distance between the two points, you're getting a vector with the distance required for *each* of the three axes.

Almost miraculously, all the other code in your script will work if you just replace the variable `distance` with `difference`

Comment: Argh... you 're absolutey right. Sometimes I think I'm totally understand the concept of vector maths and then something like this shows up :)